# What files can I move to a small (16GB) SSD to speed up Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, pagefile

I have a 16GB SSD. It's too small to install Windows on. A discussion about ReadyBoost made me think of putting it in my Core2 Duo with 4 gig of ram and put pagefile.sys on it. What else can be moved to the SSD to speed up the system? Would moving temp and tmp help, and would they fit? Any other suggestions?

Comment: You should install the core OS there, do not put files like pagefile.sys on an SSD drive, it will cause it to fail much quicker than "normal" due to excessive read/writes. You can install Windows in 16GB quite easily, and then set the Users to the spinning drive. Question is at that size drive would be where to put Program folders? They likely would have to go on the HDD for size restraints.

Comment: @acejavelin Please do not spread myths. Assuming you didn't get a dud in the first place, modern SSDs are plenty reliable enough to put a swap file onto. (Whether it would be a good idea to use the SSD for swap in the OP's situation is a different matter.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I understand and agree... Except a 16GB SSD is likely not new or modern, although the OP didn't state that. the smallest standard consumer SSD manufactured today (I believe) is 60/64GB. I made the assumption this was an older, used drive.

Comment: @acejavelin. The SSD is a nearly new KingSpec DOM that has seen 6 months of light use in my Media PC (Lubuntu + Kodi) but it went in the parts bin when I got my Orange Pi. I just want to repurpose it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling What I am trying to do is opposite of the 'common wisdom' I have Googled on the topic. While most advice is on getting the longest life out of an SSD that cost hundreds of dollars I just want some quick bang for the buck out of a spare I have lying around that originally cost about the same as a comparable thumb drive. If Microsoft thinks ReadyBoost and a USB thumb drive will help then I think a SATA SSD without ReadyBoost's read/write protection should be even better.